# No me marca error NetBeans, pero no me ejecuta el código

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me marca error NetBeans, pero no me ejecuta el código...

Comment: Por favor añade el código y los mensajes de error como texto en lugar de como imágenes. Serán más fáciles de leer y de buscar de esa manera, ayudando a otros usuarios a encontrar y responder tu pregunta. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: No te marca error de sintaxis, pero si te lo marca a la hora de la ejecución del programa.

Comment: Si la respuesta que te han dado es correcta, deberías marcarla como tal. Revisa el [tour] para ver como se hace.

Answer (score 3):

si te marca error, ahí dice **ArrayIndexOutBou..** en la **linea 15**, y es cierto tienes un arreglo de 2 posiciones y otro de 1 y tratas de recorrerlos con 4 iteraciones o ciclos. Los arreglos o vectores se recorren máximo hasta su tamaño-1; prueba esto:

```
for(n=0;n<2;n++){
nomb[n]=JOptio..Dialog("ingresa tu nombre" + name[0]);
}
for(n=0;n<2;n++){
system.out.println(noomb[n]);
}
```

trata de escribir el código que esta dentro del main.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigo!!!